# XYZ Clustering in Python and numpy arrays

Tags: python, clustering, numpy

I am looking for a method of clustering XYZ data in Python that works on numpy arrays.  I know of a few sources, such as clusterpy and Pysal but have had little success with them as they seem to still be in the development stage and do not support numpy arrays.

EDIT:

My numpy arrays are of XY points with a Z column of a value at the point such as soil moisture or plant height.  I want to spatially cluster the Z values into similar regions.

Comment: I haven't tried it but what about [scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/cluster.html)? Also, what problems are you having with what you've tried?  PySAL is fairly well established.

Comment: I am looking for clustering routines that are designed for GIS data, hence the usage of the mentioned libraries.  I think clusterpy is completely broken, and Pysal currently only implements the max-p algorithm.

Answer (score 6):

[scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/) has an extensive [clustering library](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#clustering) with many different methods available. As a bonus scikit-learn is one of the best documented Python libraries I've seen. When working with 3d point clouds I've had a lot of success with [DBSCAN](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#dbscan) for instance.

Alternately as @Fezter suggests above, [scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/cluster.html) offers two different methods of clustring: [k-means (vector-quantization)](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/cluster.vq.html#module-scipy.cluster.vq) and [hierarchical classification](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/cluster.hierarchy.html#module-scipy.cluster.hierarchy). While there isn't the number of methods available scipy is often a good place to start as the clustering methods don't tend to require as much setup.

Comment: I am looking for cluster libraries for GIS data, see my edit.